Storage location for files uploaded to Python Shiny Express application?
I'm trying to allow users to upload a file to a web app that I've built using Shiny Express for Python. I'm using the ui.input_file function for users to select the file that they'd like to upload, but the documentation doesn't mention a location where uploaded files will be stored beyond a datapath. When you try to specify the datapath like so:
from shiny import reactive
from shiny.express import input, render, ui
from shiny.types import FileInfo

ui.input_file("file1", "please select a file to upload", accept=['.csv'], multiple = False,)
                
@reactive.calc
def parsed_file():
    file: list[FileInfo] | None = input.file1()
    f = open(file[0]["datapath"], "r")
    print(f)
    return f

Nothing is returned and nothing is printed. When I change datapath to Path(__file__).parent / "./data/results/", the problem doesn't get fixed and nothing is stored in the location I've specified. I've also tried to look at my git logs to see if there are any changes when I try to upload a file, but there are no changes.
Could the file be going to my /tmp files? If so, how do I change where the file is put?

There's an example app here which does exactly what you are trying to do: https://shinylive.io/py/examples/#file-upload I think the problem with yours is that you are only opening the file, not reading it. The file has to go to tmp/ because that's where it would go if the app is deployed. If you need it to end up somewhere else, you will need to move it after it is uploaded.

Why is this question part of the ‘R language collective’ when it has nothing (as far as I can see) to do with the R language?

Try this:
from shiny import reactive
from shiny.express import input, render, ui
from shiny.types import FileInfo
import pandas as pd

ui.input_file("file1", "please select a file to upload", accept=['.csv'], multiple = False,)

@reactive.calc
def parsed_file():
    if not input.file1():
        return
    df = pd.read_csv(input.file1()[0]["datapath"])

    return df

@render.table
def summary():
    df = parsed_file()
    return df

